# Create a function to return isFullDay true

Tags: javascript, arrays

Need to create a function that will take "hours" and "isFullDay" as a parameter, hours will be an array of objects having key `opensAt` and `closesAt` having values in a string. I need to check if the store opens for 24 hours on the basis of opensAt and `closesAt` key. If it's open for 24-hours return `isFullDay` true.

```
{
  date: ISODate("12-03-2018T12:00:00"),
  hours : [{
    opensAt:"08:30",
    closesAt:"12:30"
  },
  {
    opensAt:"12:30",
    closesAt:"13:30"
  },
  {
    opensAt:"13:30",
    closesAt:"5:30"
  },
  {
    opensAt:"5:30 PM",
    closesAt:"8:30 AM"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting assignment! What have you written so far?

Comment: I tried create a variable which will store previousClosesAt and previousOpensAt and then  loop through the hours array and store the previousOpensAt and previousClosesAt for each item and check if the difference between the previousClosesAt and currentOpensAt is zero then assign both the current value to previous value.And once the loop ends,will check if opensAt and closesAt are same then it means the store is open for 24 hour.But I was not able to succeed.I think my logic was not fitting properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the *hours* array of object to be a *full-day*, we will consider it as a `circular array` and for each element following property should be satisfied

---

***hours[i].opensAt <= hours[i-1].closesAt***

Below is the code written in javascript, you can modify it to your needs, but the basic idea will be the same

```js
    function isFullday(hours) {

      let simlifiedInterval = [];

      for (let index in hours) {
        let opensAt = hours[index].opensAt.split(" ")[0].split(":");
        let closesAt = hours[index].closesAt.split(" ")[0].split(":");

        opensAt = +opensAt[0] + (opensAt[1] || 0) / 60 ;
        closesAt = +closesAt[0] + (closesAt[1] || 0)/ 60;

        simlifiedInterval[index] = { opensAt, closesAt };
      }

      let isFullDay = true, i = 1;

      for (; i < simlifiedInterval.length; i++) {
        if (simlifiedInterval[i].opensAt > simlifiedInterval[i - 1].closesAt) {
          isFullDay = false;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (isFullDay && simlifiedInterval[0].opensAt > simlifiedInterval[i - 1].closesAt)
        isFullDay = false;

      return isFullDay;
    }

    const hours_1 = [
      {
        opensAt: "08:30",
        closesAt: "12:30",
      },
      {
        opensAt: "12:30",
        closesAt: "13:30",
      },
      {
        opensAt: "13:30",
        closesAt: "5:30",
      },
      {
        opensAt: "5:30 PM",
        closesAt: "8:30 AM",
      },
    ];

    const hours_2 = [
      {
        opensAt: "08:30",
        closesAt: "12:30",
      },
      {
        opensAt: "12:30",
        closesAt: "13:30",
      },
      {
        opensAt: "13:30",
        closesAt: "5:30",
      },
    ];

    const hours_3 = [
      {
        opensAt: "08:30",
        closesAt: "12",
      },
      {
        opensAt: "12:30",
        closesAt: "13:30",
      },
      {
        opensAt: "13:30",
        closesAt: "5:30",
      },
      {
        opensAt: "5:30 PM",
        closesAt: "8:30 AM",
      },
    ];

    console.log(isFullday(hours_1));

    console.log(isFullday(hours_2));

    console.log(isFullday(hours_3));
```